# CURL not executing or returning an error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I have a dedicated server hosted at OVH and I have the following PHP CURL script that calls the Facebook Graph API to post on a user wall:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/'.$user.'/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'link='.$link.'&access_token=************');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)){
   error_log(curl_error($ch));
}
else {
   error_log($response);
}
```

The expected behavior is that the script should log the facebook response. I noticed a LOT of times, the script doesn't return ANY response at all and not even a CURL error.

I have also a script that uses `file_get_contents`. I noticed also that every few days I suddenly get a huge amount of `connection timed out` calling the Facebook Graph API. It happens randomly and for no reason!
When I try to call the same URL from browser immediately after it's logged in the error log, it works successfully.

I'm really confused :( Do you think these are connectivity issues with OVH servers or the Graph API or what?

Thanks

Comment: Fetching a URL that your server can’t connect to via your browser instead proves very little. A connectivity issue with your host is likely. As the server admin to investigate, check the logs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

wanted to comment, not post an answer but I don't have enough rep :(

For https using curl I usually add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

Comment: I know about this but it was never a problem to  not have it. I believe something else is going on

Comment: Well, have you tried it? Also, rather than trying in a browser, can you use something like wget on the server itself?